# Why is @PostConstruct not being called in an Arquillian test

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi, jboss-arquillian

Because the `@BeforeClass` callback does not work for arquillian tests, I tried to initialize some fields in the `@PostConstruct` callback of my test. There is a `beans.xml` in the deployment and I have also tried adding a `@Startup` annotation and a no-arg constructor, but to no effect. Although CDI is working, and all injections are being performed for other fields of the test, `@PostConstruct` is not being called. Am I missing something?

I am using `Arquillian 1.0.0.Final` on `JBoss 7.1.1.Final`.
I am not looking for a workaround - I could just use the `@Before` callback. But this would clearly be suboptimal as I need to initialize the values just once for all tests. And more importantly, the observed behaviour seems to contradict my understanding of CDI.

Here is the gist of my test:

```
    @RunWith(Arquillian.class)
    public class UploadResetterTest {

        @Deployment
        public static Archive<?> createTestArchive() {

            return ShrinkWrap
                    .create(WebArchive.class, "uploadResetTest.war")
                    .addPackages(true, "my.package")
                    .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
        }

        Map<String, String> predicates = new HashMap<String, String>();

        @Inject
        Logger log;

        @PostConstruct
        public void postConstruct() {
            log.info("postconstruct");

            // here I am trying to fill the map
            predicates.put("type", UploadTypes.TALLY.toString());
        }

        @Test
        public void testResetTallies() throws Exception {

           // here the map is still empty
            predicates.get("type");
    }
```

Comment: what would happen if you did in a method annotated @Deployment ? Im not really good with Arquillan tho

Comment: @AkselWillgert - funny thing - it doesn't work either - I made the map static and tried to fill it in the `@Deployment` method, but it is still empty. It works fine with `@Before` though, so it's not the map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@PostConstruct` would not be invoked for a test class instance used in an Arquillian test. While Arquillian performs non-contextual CDI injection into the injection points of a test class instance, it is not responsible for constructing the instance itself (JUnit or TestNG does this), and neither is construction of the test class instance managed by the CDI container or any other service container (this explains why `@PostConstruct` is ignored).

You're best bet therefore is to use `@Before`. You do raise a good point though, and it might be worth investigating whether the JUnit and TestNG runners provide hooks so that CDI or other DI providers can manage or hook into the test instance lifecycle.

Comment: Thank you, Vineet. That does explain it. I will post in the qruillian forum WRT global fixtures.